# Unexpected results when returning long long in a method call

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've encountered a strange occurrence when I pass a long long value back from a method call. In my app I've already worked around this but I am curious to know why this is.

Can someone explain to me, when I have a method as defined:

```
- (long long)testLong {
    NSString* longString = @"100000133597162";
    long long retval = [longString longLongValue];
    NSLog(@"retval:%lld",retval);
    return retval;
}
```

and I call the method like so:

```
long long test = [self testLong];
NSLog(@"test:%lld",test);
```

The results are:

```
retval:100000133597162
test:410044394
```

It seems so bizarre to me. The correct value is printed out while inside the method. But once outside the method it seems to be a totally different value. I have stepped through using the debugger and it reveals the same thing - two different values. I just can't seem to explain it. Anyone?

Comment: Strange, your code works ok for me.

Comment: Do you have the same signature in your header file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a "totally different value"; `410044394` is the low 32 bits of `100000133597162`.  You almost certainly have simply neglected to include a header file, or have the method declared as returning a `long` or `int` somewhere.

If your calling function can't figure out what the correct return type is, it will assume that it is type `id`, which is 32 bits wide on the iPhone, which would produce exactly the truncation that you're seeing here.

Similarly, if your calling function has a prototype that declares the return type to be something 32 bits wide on the iPhone (like `long` or `int`), you will see the same truncation effect.

Comment: you are correct. I neglected to leave it out the prototype out of the header actually. Once i stuck it in there everything looks good. Thank you